# How can I fix Debian Linux nf_conntrack?

Tags: linux, debian

I have a problem with my Linux router (Debian). When I run MTR, it always has loss in 1 hop it in my server.

My friends told me it's because my `nf_conntrack` is full. I have been up `max_conntrack` but that's just temporary.

I read that `nf_conntrack` can be flushed, but when I tried I got an error:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 1677216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 1677216
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 64000
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 1
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 54000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 120
net.netfilter.nf_contrack_max = 1024000
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
error: permission denied on key 'net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count'
```

[image: nf_conntrack screenshot]

Comment: Can you explain what this means "had loss in 1 hop it in my server"?  Where are you running the MTR and where is the endpoint?  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I may say something dumb not wouldn't any hop which passes the traffic through it decrease the TTL by one? Isn't that what you're observing?

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because you are using DROP in your firewall policy. Try to change DROP to REJECT in your rules.
More details [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject)

Comment: http://www.mardahl.dk/2010/11/22/i-dont-want-to-read-more-or-click-here/

Comment: @trig do you have any comments on topic?

Comment: It was a suggestion on a simple way you could improve your answer, but it seems you couldn't be bothered.